# ChainLink Any API Large Response Example doesnt fulfill

Tags: oracle, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, chainlink

I took the example from the [official ChainLink Any API Large Response docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) and deployed it to the kovan network without any changes.

The contract: https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x1B0beB43a03591bc7f8B5eFf1F0bfB8400e12a63
Compiler: `0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7`

I also verified it's code to be sure that it matches with the example from docs, fund it with 2 LINK tokens. Then I called `requestBytes` method twice, one 8 hours ago and another 7 hours ago:
[image]

Both finished without any errors, but when i'm reading `data` and `image_url` they're empty:

[image]

[Getting `uint256`](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) works fine, the problem arises only with Large Responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That demo broke due to API changes in the ChainlinkClient and Operator.sol contracts.

The [demo has now been updated](https://docs.chain.link/docs/large-responses/) and should work. Note that the function for sending the Chainlink request has changed to `sendOperatorRequest()` (for large response requests.)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I eventually ended up triggering `Get Uint256` Job multiple times to get all the data that i needed